# Not found Error when calling Salesforce Rest API for creating/fetching a Case number from Service Console

Tags: javascript, rest-api, case, service-cloud-console

I am tying to use Salesforce Service console to fetch Cases/ Tickets via Rest API in my Node JS application. I created a an Authorization API which will provide me with the Session Id.

Below is the sample cURL command I used to just test the API for fetching all the Cases,

```
curl https://ap17.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/00001026  -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX"
```

Unfortunately, I am always getting the same response,

```
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Could not find a match for URL"}]
```

I am really not sure if I am going in the correct path here to fetch. All the API documentation is pointing me to the above Url to fetch Cases from my salesforce service console.

Comment: Please don't put your session id in a post. That's a security risk for your org.

Comment: @DavidReed: Sorry, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your resource needs to match the correct URI:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Cases/*')
```

IF it doesn't have the wildcard, your request won't match the URL and you'd get this error.

Comment: You mean I have to use the wildcard *? I am not able to understand

Comment: @Owner Yes, your apex must use the wildcard for proper mapping to the URL you're trying to use.

Comment: But the apex api is correct right?

Comment: I tried using https://ap17.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/*, and still nothing

Comment: @Owner no, the urlMapping must use the wild card. The endpoint you call should not have a wild card in it.

Comment: AM really not able to understand, on the wild card concept here. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Owner There's an example of the wild cards in my answer already.

Comment: Or could you please tell me, where could I specify the resource. I am all new to Salesforce

Comment: @Owner In your **Apex** code, you use the RestResource annotation.